# SQL- Add digit (0) to specific location in existing entry (Varchar) to lengthen all entries by one

Tags: sql, sql-update, sql-like

I want to lengthen several event numbers by adding a 0 after the first two digits. The first two digits represent the year. Ex. I want to change 121023 to 1201023. So I want to change ALL event numbers (Varchar) that start with 12 to start with 120 by adding the 0 in to lengthen ALL of the event numbers by one.

This is what I have so far:

```
UPDATE EVENT 
SET EVNT_URI = '***what do I put here?***' 
WHERE EVNT_URI IN(SELECT EVNT_URI FROM EVENT WHERE EVNT_URI LIKE '12%')
```

The reason I am doing this is that the 12 represents the year and the event numbers are getting close to 130000. All of the event numbers are 6 digits and I want to change them to 7 digits by adding a zero after the first to digits which represent the year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
update event
set evnt_Uri = evnt_Uri + 1080000
where evnt_Uri between 120000 and 129999
```

Although if these aren't numbers, but simply a string formed of numerical characters, one might argue they shouldn't be stored as int at all